# Flexbox: 4 items per row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using a flex box to display 8 items that will dynamically resize with my page. How do I force it to split the items into two rows? (4 per row)?

Here is a relevant snip:

(Or if you prefer jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vivmaha/oq6prk1p/2/)

```css
.parent-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent-wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: [Update] This question was based on a poor unresponsive design. If you find yourself using one of the answers below, be careful. In a good design, you'd have more items on wider screens, and fewer on smaller screens. Forcing 4 items for all screen sizes will only look appealing on a narrow range of screen widths.

Comment: I don't agree with the "in a good design" statement at all. What if I'm making a calendar widget and I want it to always have 7 days per row? What if I'm building a Sudoku board and it always needs to be 9x9? There are plenty of valid reasons why someone might want to hard-code the number of items per row, and that doesn't always make it bad design.

Comment: @OOPSStudio Your examples can all be solved with `grid` instead of `flex`. And that's a different story from this original question

Answer (score 719, accepted):

You've got `flex-wrap: wrap` on the container. That's good, because it overrides the default value, which is `nowrap` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)). This is the reason items don't wrap to form a grid in [some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45379566/3597276).

In this case, the main problem is `flex-grow: 1` on the flex items.

The `flex-grow` property doesn't actually size flex items. Its task is to distribute free space in the container ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)). So no matter how small the screen size, each item will receive a proportional part of the free space on the line.

More specifically, there are eight flex items in your container. With `flex-grow: 1`, each one receives 1/8 of the free space on the line. Since there's no content in your items, they can shrink to zero width and will never wrap.

The solution is to define a width on the items. Try this:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  flex: 1 0 21%; /* explanation below */
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

With `flex-grow: 1` defined in the `flex` shorthand, there's no need for `flex-basis` to be 25%, which would actually result in three items per row due to the margins.

Since `flex-grow` will consume free space on the row, `flex-basis` only needs to be large enough to enforce a wrap. In this case, with `flex-basis: 21%`, there's plenty of space for the margins, but never enough space for a fifth item.

Comment: I like this because it worked for me, but “plenty of space” makes me feel a little uneasy.  Is there some tiny window or situation where this “estimation” might fail me?

Comment: What sort of situation? In most layouts there are extreme cases that can create problems. Such cases normally sail through cost-benefit analyses because they never, or almost never, occur. For instance, in the solution above, if you put in very large margins, the layout may break. If that's an issue, then it should be posted in the question. @Jackson

Comment: “if you put in very large margins, the layout may break”  That’s an example of a scenario I’d like to avoid.  I don’t care about practicality; entertain my adoration for perfection.  Is there any way to be more exact?

Comment: You can also use `flex: 1 0 calc(25% - 10px);`

Comment: This kind of an approach is more typically handled by padding and negative margins on the parent, which will allow you to actually use the full 25% `flex-basis`. This was the yesteryear implementation in most grid libraries.

Comment: Great answer! A small improvement I use is `margin: 2%;` instead of a fixed pixel number in order to prevent the boxes from jumping to a new line on small devices/resolutions. the general formula is `(100 - (4 * box-width-percent)) / 8`% for different box widths

Comment: In case anyone forgets, the flex property here is shorthand for 
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: 21%;

Comment: Another way I like to deal with wrapping and dynamic margins that arent negative is to use the + selector and then use nth-child for where I want to wrap. Something like:  .child+.child { margin-left: 2% } then .child:nth-child(3n +1) { margin-left: 0%; } or something like that

Comment: You can check this approach also https://stackoverflow.com/a/45038018/3448527

Comment: Every time I use flex for something cool like this I am so grateful we're not back in the dark days of web development

Answer (score 138):

Add a width to the `.child` elements. I personally would use percentages on the `margin-left` if you want to have it always 4 per row.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vivmaha/oq6prk1p/9)**

```
.child {
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
    margin: 10px 0 0 2%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 100px;
    width: calc(100% * (1/4) - 10px - 1px);
}
```

Comment: Good idea. I used this idea with minor edits. http://jsfiddle.net/vivmaha/oq6prk1p/6/

Comment: Ah. This actually doesn't solve my problem. See here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/vivmaha/oq6prk1p/7/. I do not have the liberty of using percentages for my margin. They must be a fixed width. This means that the magic 23% that we chose won't work since it doesn't take the fixed margin into account.

Comment: Yes, calc solves it! 'calc(100% * (1/4) - 10px - 1px)'. See http://jsfiddle.net/vivmaha/oq6prk1p/9/

Comment: Then what's the use of flex in this, still?

Comment: What about responsive design? We don't want to put a fixed width on child

Comment: how can i do this if i want two elements per row ?

Answer (score 70):

Here is another apporach.

You can accomplish it in this way too:

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child{
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Sample:
https://codepen.io/capynet/pen/WOPBBm

And a more complete sample:
https://codepen.io/capynet/pen/JyYaba

Comment: What about if I have less then 4 child? I dislike that blank empty space, the child are not responsive...

Comment: The other answer by Muddasir Abbas uses only flex settings, so I think it's a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 46):

I would do it like this using negative margins and calc for the gutters:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.child {
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/9j2rvom4/

---

### Alternative CSS Grid Method:

```
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/jc2utfs3/

Comment: this one not only works but keeps the div centered too. Better for my situations than the flexbox ones

Comment: I believe that css grid is supported well enough now to safely use it

Answer (score 41):

For more detail you can follow this [Link](https://antibland.github.io/front-end/project_files/css/flexbox_max_items_per_row.html)

```css
.parent{ 
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
}

.parent .child{ 
  flex: 1 1 25%;
  /*Start Run Code Snippet output CSS*/
  padding: 5px; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  /*End Run Code Snippet output CSS*/
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, to easily control the amount of columns you can `flex: 1 1 calc(100% / 6)`

Answer (score 4):

I believe this example is more barebones and **easier to understand** then @dowomenfart.

```
.child {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1em;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: calc(25% - 2em);
}
```

This accomplishes the same width calculations while cutting straight to the meat. The math is way easier and `em` is the [new standard](https://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/) due to its scalability and mobile-friendliness.

Comment: em is not really the new standard. It can be a pain in the ass, and designers don't design with EM's in mind.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.parent-wrapper {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
 .parent {
 display: flex;
 font-size: 0;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 margin-right: -10px;
 margin-bottom: -10px;
}
 .child {
 background: blue;
 height: 100px;
 flex-grow: 1;
 flex-shrink: 0;
 flex-basis: calc(25% - 10px);
}
 .child:nth-child(even) {
 margin: 0 10px 10px 10px;
 background-color: lime;
}
 .child:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: orange; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style type="text/css">

 </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="parent-wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

;)

Comment: If you can please add some context about why this answers the OP question rather than just posting code.

Comment: if you add `justify-content: space-evenly;` to the prent, then they align nicely and you don't have to do the `calc` on the child. Thanks for the example, though!

Answer (score 2):

## Flex wrap + negative margin

**Why flex vs. `display: inline-block`?**

- Flex gives more flexibility with elements sizing
- Built-in white spacing collapsing (see [3 inline-block divs with exactly 33% width not fitting in parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653017))

**Why negative margin?**

Either you use SCSS or CSS-in-JS for the edge cases (i.e. first element in column), or you set a default margin and get rid of the outer margin later.

### Implementation

https://codepen.io/zurfyx/pen/BaBWpja

```
<div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="elementContainer">
            <div class="element">
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

```
:root {
  --columns: 2;
  --betweenColumns: 20px; /* This value is doubled when no margin collapsing */
}

.outerContainer {
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide the negative margin */
}

.container {
    background-color: grey;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: calc(-1 * var(--betweenColumns));
}

.elementContainer {
    display: flex; /* To prevent margin collapsing */
    width: calc(1/var(--columns) * 100% - 2 * var(--betweenColumns));
    margin: var(--betweenColumns);
}

.element {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 42px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```css
.parent-wrapper {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.parent {
    display: grid;
    font-size: 0;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
}
.child {
    background:blue;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height:100px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.child:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="parent-wrapper">
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/samet19/gdntwLhb/

Comment: The questioner ask for flex but you answered grid.

Answer (score -14):

Here's another way without using `calc()`.

```
// 4 PER ROW
// 100 divided by 4 is 25. Let's use 21% for width, and the remainder 4% for left & right margins...
.child {
  margin: 0 2% 0 2%;
  width: 21%;
}

// 3 PER ROW
// 100 divided by 3 is 33.3333... Let's use 30% for width, and remaining 3.3333% for sides (hint: 3.3333 / 2 = 1.66666)
.child {
  margin: 0 1.66666% 0 1.66666%;
  width: 30%;
}

// and so on!
```

That's all there is to it. You can get fancy with the dimensions to get a more aesthetic sizes but this is the idea.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but the CSS syntax is wrong (CSS values are not quoted, and declarations should end in a semi-colon) so it definitely won't work in its current form.