# Move last element to next line in a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this structure in my HTML code:

```
<div style="display:flex">
    <div class="div_first">1</div>
    <div class="div_second">2</div>
    <div class="div_third">3</div>
    <div class="div_next_line">
      <div class="div_first">4</div>
      <div class="div_second">5</div>
      <div class="div_third">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to have 4 5 6 in second line with the same columns as 1 2 3, like so:

```
1    2    3
4    5    6
```

The structure of the HTML code cannot be changed.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Apply `flex-wrap` to the container.

Apply `flex: 1 0 33%` to the first three child divs.

To the fourth div apply `flex-basis: 100%; display: flex`.

To the children of the fourth div apply  `flex: 1 0 33%`.

The idea is to force the fourth item to wrap, then have its children replicate the behavior of the children in the primary container.

Comment: Thanks, flex-basis: 100% helps me.

Answer (score 13):

Use `flex-wrap` for the parent and `flex-basis` for the children:

CSS:

```css
.parent {
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   width: 400px;
   border: 2px solid blue;
}
.parent > .div_next_line {
   display: flex;
}
.parent > div {
   display: inline-block;
   flex-grow: 1;
   flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
}
.parent > div > div {
   display: inline-block;
   flex-grow: 1;
   flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ghjbhjLu/1/

References:

[CSS Tricks | Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[Force n items, SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546550/how-to-force-a-flex-box-to-display-4-items-per-row)

Comment: I said that I can't change structure of HTML code, you provided example with changed structure.