# Arrange 2 items per row using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Imagine I have following markup

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

and style

```css
.item {
  width: 100%
}
```

and due to certain reasons I can't change the width of the 
`.item`
Can I arrange 2 items in each row by styling parent container `.container`, using flexbox or any other way?

Answer (score 298, accepted):

You can give `flex: 50%` to children `div`s without touching .`item`

```css
.item {
  width: 100%
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > div {
  flex: 50%; /* or - flex: 0 50% - or - flex-basis: 50% - */
  /*demo*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: He said he couldn't change the width of the divs, you just did that with a different selector

Comment: I assume this: `Assuming .item is used globally so you cannot change the style of it`

Comment: If that was the case, wouldn't OP give it another class?

Comment: description of `flex` on css-tricks.com: this is the shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis combined. The second and third parameters (flex-shrink and flex-basis) are optional. Default is 0 1 auto.

Comment: if you only have one element, you also need `max-width: 50 %;` ...?

Comment: not true. use have to stop the flex item to grow so either use either one of my other "or" options given in the answer `flex: 0 50%` or `flex-basis: 50%`

Comment: I don't understand why you need the selector `.container > div`?? Why can't you just put it into the `.item` selector? It selects the same!

Comment: @Black you're right, but IP mentioned didn't want/couldn't touch that selector.

Comment: If you add a further 5th row (or any even number), then the last row will take the whole line space. How can we prevent that?

Comment: @micgala you have to use `flex-grow: 0` , or the other options I gave in the answer ` `flex: 0 50%` (where `0` is flex-grow) or just use `flex-basis: 50%` so `flex-grow` will keep its default value , I have already replied to a similar comment in this answer a [little bit up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037844/arrange-2-items-per-row-using-flexbox/45038018?noredirect=1#comment123370119_45038018)

Answer (score 8):

The below solution worked for me

```
.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child{
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Sample: https://codepen.io/capynet/pen/WOPBBm

Comment: `flex-wrap` is the important part here, providing you have already set `flex: 50%` on the children.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the width property must not be changed, I can think of a few possible solutions, the first being `fit-content` which has amazingly poor browser support. The second, is use positioning, which is an equally bad idea due to its finicky nature and likelihood to fail on different screen sizes.

Now the last two, are very similar, one is to use two containers, give them `display:inline;` give them a limited width, and fill them with items. If you didn't notice, this is essentially a 2×1 table.

Lastly you could make a 2×1 table, and while it is probably the easiest solution here, it is a bad idea to get in the habit of using tables to position things other than forms and tables. However, it is an option that I will make available to you.

Good luck!