# Flex items not respecting margins and box-sizing: border-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve a simple thing that we have in standard CSS.

Let's say that I have a grid system with 3 columns and `box-sizing: border-box`.

That means that I will fit 3 boxes and with a margin that will shrink the size to fit max 3 boxes.

But when I try to do that with FLEXBOX, it's a pain!!

So if I have div's with `flex: 1 1 33.33%;  margin: 10px;` I was expecting to have 3 boxes per row... but if I use `flex-wrap: wrap`, that will not shrink to fit 3 boxes .

Here is a example.. the idea is that the second row would have 3 boxes in a row and fourth box would be in the last row.

Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/mariohmol/pbkzj984/14/

```css
.horizontal-layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 400px;
}

header>span {
  /* flex: 1 1 100%; */
  /* flex: 1 0 100%; */
  flex: 1 1 33.33%;
  margin: 10px;
}

header>.button {
  background-color: grey;
}

header>.app-name {
  background-color: orange;
}

header#with-border-padding {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

header#with-border-padding>span {
  flex: 1 1 33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* this is not useful at all */
}

header#with-border-padding>.button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
NO flex-wrap: wrap, so it not respects the flex 33% <br/>
<header class="horizontal-layout">
  <span class="button">A</span>
  <span class="app-name">B</span>
  <span class="button">C</span>
  <span class="button">D</span>
</header>
<br/><br/> WITH flex-wrap: wrap : I expect to have 3 boxes in first row and D box in a down<br/>
<header id="with-border-padding" class="horizontal-layout">
  <span class="button">A</span>
  <span class="app-name">B</span>
  <span class="button">C</span>
  <span class="button">D</span>
</header>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Keep in mind that `box-sizing: border-box` brings padding and borders into the width / height calculation, *but not margins*. Margins are always calculated separately.

The `box-sizing` property takes two values:

- `content-box`
- `border-box`

It does not offer `padding-box` or `margin-box`.

Consider those terms when referring to the [CSS Box Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html).

[image]

<sup>source: [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html)</sup>

> [**3.1. Changing the Box Model: the `box-sizing`
>   property**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#box-sizing)
>
> **`content-box`**
>
> The specified width and height apply to the width and height respectively
>   of the content box of the element. The padding and border of the
>   element are laid out and drawn outside the specified width and height.
>
> **`border-box`**
>
> Length and percentages values for width and height on this element
>   determine the border box of the element. That is, any padding or
>   border specified on the element is laid out and drawn inside this
>   specified width and height. The content width and height are
>   calculated by subtracting the border and padding widths of the
>   respective sides from the specified width and height properties.

---

Also, an initial setting of a flex container is [**`flex-shrink: 1`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-shrink-property). This means that flex items can shrink in order to fit within the container.

Therefore, a specified `width`, `height` or `flex-basis` will not hold, unless `flex-shrink` is disabled.

You can override the default with `flex-shrink: 0`.

Here's a more complete explanation: [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)

---

**Here's a simple solution:**

You have four boxes. You want three on row 1 and the last on row 2.

This is what you have:

```
flex: 1 1 33.33%;
margin: 10px;
```

This breaks down to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 33.33%`

We know that `box-sizing: border-box` factors padding and borders into the `flex-basis`. That's not a problem. But what about the margins?

Well, since you have `flex-grow: 1` on each item, there is no need for `flex-basis` to be 33.33%.

Since `flex-grow` will consume any free space on the row, `flex-basis` only needs to be large enough to enforce a wrap.

Since margins also consume free space, `flex-grow` will not intrude into the margin space.

So try this instead:

```
flex: 1 1 26%;
margin: 10px;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.horizontal-layout {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
}

header > span { 
  flex: 1 0 26%;                    /* ADJUSTED */
  margin: 10px;
}

header#with-border-padding {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

header#with-border-padding>span {
  flex: 1 0 26%;                   /* ADJUSTED */
}

header#with-border-padding>.button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

header>.button {
  background-color: grey;
}

header>.app-name {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
NO flex-wrap: wrap, so it not respects the flex 33% <br/>
<header class="horizontal-layout">
  <span class="button">A</span>
  <span class="app-name">B</span>
  <span class="button">C</span>
  <span class="button">D</span>
</header>
<br/><br/> WITH flex-wrap: wrap : I expect to have 3 boxes in first row and D box in a down<br/>
<header id="with-border-padding" class="horizontal-layout">
  <span class="button">A</span>
  <span class="app-name">B</span>
  <span class="button">C</span>
  <span class="button">D</span>
</header>
```

Comment: thank you.. good explanation.. this is kind what i was looking for

Comment: before reading this comment, I had two columns `col1 - flex: 1.25`, `col2 - flex: 0.75` which gave me padding issues..
Now I've changed to `col1 - flex: 1 1 62.5%`, `col2 - flex: 1 1 37.5%` no more padding issues, many thanks!!

Comment: How did you know to choose 26% for 3 elements per row? Did you have to do some maths?

Comment: See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45384426/3597276) for a more detailed explanation.  @Embedded_Mugs

Answer (score 1):

As well pointed out in [Michael_B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45059944/1548895) margins are not taken into account when calculating flex item width. But you can subtract `margin`s from `flex-basis` to get desired behaviour.

For current case:

```
header > span {
  /* 33.33% - margin-left - margin-right */
  flex: 1 1 calc(33.33% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Also you should set `box-sizing: border-box` to include padding (and borders) when calculating `width`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.horizontal-layout {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
}

header > span { 
  flex: 1 0 calc(33.33% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
}

header#with-border-padding {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

header#with-border-padding > span {
  flex: 1 0 calc(33% - 20px);
}

header#with-border-padding > .button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

header > .button {
  background-color: grey;
}

header > .app-name {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
NO flex-wrap: wrap, so it not respects the flex 33% <br/>
<header class="horizontal-layout">
  <span class="button">A</span>
  <span class="app-name">B</span>
  <span class="button">C</span>
  <span class="button">D</span>
</header>
<br/><br/> WITH flex-wrap: wrap : I expect to have 3 boxes in first row and D box in a down<br/>
<header id="with-border-padding" class="horizontal-layout">
  <span class="button">A</span>
  <span class="app-name">B</span>
  <span class="button">C</span>
  <span class="button">D</span>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. i thought about calc but think that i have a grid system where use something like `col-md-3` , so would be difficult to use that and different margins for different containers.. so i was not considering calc

Comment: @mariomol Then you could wrap you blocks in such classes and use margins in inner blocks.