# Using Flexbox with padding in the inner items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I maintain width ratio defined by `flex-grow` between two items when one of which is partially filled with padding? It does not work. Ratio depends on the container width.

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="flex-grow: 3; padding: 4rem; background-color: red;">
  </div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 2; background-color: green;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is wrong? like what result do you expect?

Comment: When you try it there is no 3:2 width ratio.

Comment: Ratio depends on the container width.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [**`flex-grow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) property is not designed for precision sizing of flex items. It's job is to distribute space in the container among flex items. So `flex-grow` is not the best tool for this job.

Instead, use [**`flex-basis`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis), which is the equivalent of `width` or `height` (depending on `flex-direction`) in a flex container.

Then add [**`box-sizing: border-box`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45059944/3597276) to integrate the padding into the flex item's width.

[revised fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/267shddd/3/)

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="flex-basis: 60%; padding: 4rem ; background-color: red; box-sizing: border-box;">
  </div>
  <div style="flex-basis: 40%; background-color: green;">  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `width` (or `flex-basis`) instead of `flex-grow`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Don't forgert this to include padding/border inside width calculation */
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;height:20px;margin-bottom:10px;">
  <div style="flex-grow: 3;  background-color: red;">
  </div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 2; background-color: green;">
  </div>
</div>
replace by width
<div style="display: flex;height:20px;margin-bottom:10px;">
  <div style="width:calc((3 / 5) * 100%);  background-color: red;">
  </div>
  <div style="width:calc((2 / 5) * 100%); background-color: green;">
  </div>
</div>
then add padding
<div style="display: flex;margin-bottom:10px;">
  <div style="width:calc((3 / 5) * 100%); padding:3rem; background-color: red;">
  </div>
  <div style="width:calc((2 / 5) * 100%); background-color: green;">
  </div>
</div>
same result with flex-basis
<div style="display: flex;margin-bottom:10px;">
  <div style="flex-basis:calc((3 / 5) * 100%); padding:3rem; background-color: red;">
  </div>
  <div style="flex-basis:calc((2 / 5) * 100%); background-color: green;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually doing padding style in the inner tag of the inner items:

```
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="flex-grow: 3; background-color: red;">
    <div style="padding: 4rem;">Some content</div>
  </div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 2; background-color: green;">
    Some content
  </div>
</div>
```