# How can I apply margins so that elements don't exceed 100% width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width, margin

I have **[this layout](https://codepen.io/SirExotic/pen/xjaRNd)** and I want to be able to add a *margin* around every element but without changing the *widths* of each element.

I know that, for example with the `header`, I am able to apply a `margin: 10px;` (let's focus on the left and right margin) and a `width: calc(100% - 20px)` which takes away 20px from the 100% to account for the margin.

**Question**:
Is there a way to do this without changing the width?

So I can keep the width 100% and not have to worry about how much margin I apply to the elements?

Comment: Margins and width/height are like oil and water. They don't blend. So the answer to your question is "no". However, if you're open to other spacing options, there are many. Here's a start: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45057867/3597276

Comment: you could use a border instead using `box-sizing: border-box`. Or a inner outline or an inset box-shadow

Comment: In your case you can't do it without changing width but you can do it by removing width. Divs will fit to available space, considering margins.

Comment: @rpm192 Have you read the question at all? If you go to my example you can see I am using Flexbox already. I explained that I do not want to change the percentages of each element's width, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with `flex-grow`. In your case you have width defined in this way: `20% + 60% + 20%` which is `20% + 3*20% + 20%` so we have factors like that `1 + 3 + 1`. So use these factors to setup `flex-grow` then you can easily add margin like you want.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #333D4E;
}


/* Main */

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

article {
  flex-grow: 3;
  min-height: 800px;
  background: #EDF0F1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

nav {
  flex-grow: 1;
  order: -1;
  min-height: 800px;
  background: #9AA4A6;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

aside {
  flex-grow: 1;
  order: 1;
  min-height: 800px;
  background: #6295D6;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>Main Content</article>
  <nav>Side Nav</nav>
  <aside>Aside</aside>
</main>
```

The same apply to a single element:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  display:flex;
}

.container {
  min-height:200px;
  flex-grow:1;
  margin:0 25px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

So the trick is to find the correct `flex-grow` value to use.