# Flexbox showing dynamic number of items with 5 items per row using flex basis to consume extra space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to show 5 items per row using flexbox.

```css
.parent-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 181px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  flex: 1 1 calc(100% * (1/5) - 10px - 1px);
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent-wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want to use the flex grow, so that resize will not affect the data displayed. This code above will stretch the data if the row less than 5 items. If i didnt use the flex grow, it works fine for the view, but when resizing there will show some blank space after the data displayed.

If without flex grow, how can i consume extra space by just using the flex basis

> calc(100% * (1/5) - 10px - 1px)

Comment: Possible of duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546550/flexbox-4-items-per-row

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802202/how-to-center-a-flex-container-but-left-align-flex-items

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it seems that you are looking for the `justify-content` property. You want to remove space following the items while also preventing them from stretching. By setting `justify-content: space-between` you can achieve the desired effect. It will create an even space *between* the items but not after or before. I also set `flex-grow: 0 0` as I assume you don't want your items to grow or shrink.

Here is a link to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp) listing all possible values for `justify-content` if `space-between` is not the layout you need. For example, you also have the option to `center` your items in order to consume the extra space.

```css
.parent-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 181px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
  justify-content: space-between; /* Spaces items evenly between each other */
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% * (1/5) - 10px - 1px); /* Setting 0 (none) for flex-grow and 0 for flex shrink */
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really, i want the next row 4 items aligned like the first row 5 items. The last 5th's item will left blank. Without the flex grow = 1, when i resizing my page, it will shows extra space behind. Not fully used of the space.

Answer (score 0):

I create example for you, can try

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 1px;
  align-items: center; 
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px;  
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div
```

Comment: And if you want that items move down if you resize window you must set width and height in percentage for container block

Comment: possible to use flex-grow = 1 and maintain the next row data same width as others?