# How to avoid "box item" from wrapping content?

Tags: html, css

Why my box item is wrap i want align with both side and right side spacing of 2px also i attache screenshot what i want. Thanks

[image: I want below images design]

```css
body { padding: 0 30px; }
.banner { background-color: #3b524c; height: 550px; }
.box ul { margin: 20px -2px 0 0; padding: 0; width: auto; }
.box ul li { width: 25%; margin-right: 2px; float: left; list-style: none; display: block; padding: 29px 0; font-size: 16px; line-height: 23px; text-transform: uppercase; background-color: #e57b76; color: #d8d8d8; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<section class="banner"></section>
<section class="box">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: in case you want to do the same with flexbox and CSS-grid : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020698/how-to-add-1px-margin-to-a-flex-item-that-is-flex-0-0-25/53020778#53020778

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because **math**. You can't have 4 times `width:25%` ***AND*** extra margins. It adds up to more than 100%.

Change the width to adjust for the extra margin using `calc`.

```css
body {
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.banner {
  background-color: #3b524c;
  height: 50px;
}

.box ul {
  margin: 20px -2px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}

.box ul li {
  width: calc(25% - 2px);
  margin-right: 2px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 29px 0;
  fnt-size: 16px;
  line-height: 23px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #e57b76;
  color: #d8d8d8;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner"></section>
<section class="box">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Or he could use `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: Ah no, I just read mdn again, no margin included using that too.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the above image you just need to add a

```
    display: flex;
```

to the "ul" element in your CSS.  However depending on the intended behaviour you might not want to be using a "UL".  If it's only ever going to be the four items you might want to consider using "div" instead.  I've also done a [codepen](https://codepen.io/kriddy800/pen/EOWLaM) to show it with the flex