# Using flex to align items that have flex already?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to have a container with many child tiles of content inside. Each child tile contains data that I want centered so that is why `flex` is on the child -- so that I can align the tile content.
I want to align 3 to a line evenly so I put `flex` on the parent class and wanted to `space-evenly` but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
      <img src="">
      <span>TITLE</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
      <img src="">
      <span>TITLE</span>
  </div>  
  <div class="child">
      <img src="">
      <span>TITLE</span>
  </div>  
  <div class="child">
      <img src="">
      <span>TITLE</span>
  </div>  
  <div class="child">
      <img src="">
      <span>TITLE</span>
  </div>  
  <div class="child">
      <img src="">
      <span>TITLE</span>
  </div>  
  <div class="child">
      <img src="">
      <span>TITLE</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1200px;
}

.child {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-bottom: 26px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 396px;
    height:396px;
}
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546550/flexbox-4-items-per-row

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You had a few key things missing. Number one, your parent container was missing the class `parent` so that CSS never hit its target. Opening tag is now:

```
<div class="container parent">
```

Next I added an important flex property to the `.parent` CSS rule, allowing the items to wrap, otherwise theres no way you can get 3-across with more than 3 items:

```
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Adding `space-between` to `.parent` makes sure the items go edge to edge regardless of the width and space between items:

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

Then I added a width to the `.child` elements that is flexible that creates the 3-across layout. I used `calc` as a quick way to get some space between the elements instead of them touching horizontally:

```
width: calc(33.333% - 20px);
```

Also threw little images in there to see more of the inner flex effect too. Hope this helps!

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1200px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.child {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 26px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: calc(33.333% - 20px);
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container parent">
  <div class="child">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/40">
      <span>TITLE 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/40">
      <span>TITLE 2</span>
  </div>  
  <div class="child">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/40">
      <span>TITLE 3</span>
  </div>  
  <div class="child">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/40">
      <span>TITLE 4</span>
  </div>  
  <div class="child">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/40">
      <span>TITLE 5</span>
  </div>  
  <div class="child">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/40">
      <span>TITLE 6</span>
  </div>  
  <div class="child">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/40">
      <span>TITLE 7</span>
  </div>

</div>
```