# Is there a way to map an array of objects using a for loop?

Tags: react-native

I am attempting to map an array of objects (photo details) into a component so that it will line them up in rows with three (3) components in each row (three images).

I have tried creating a nested for loop to have the components print out like I described but to no avail. I am fairly new to React Native, but have been programming in other languages (C, Java, Javascript) for years.

Here is my code thus far:

```
class PhotoList extends Component {
    render() {
        var payments = [];

        for(let j = 0; j < PHOTO_DATA.length; J++){
            payments.push(
                <View>
            )
            for(let i = 0; i < 3 || j < PHOTO_DATA.length; i++){
                j = j + 1;
                payments.push(
                    <Photo key={i} {...PHOTO_DATA.pop} press={this.props.press} />
                )
            }
            payments.push(
                </View>
            )
        }

        return (
            <View style={photoList.container}>
                <ScrollView>
                    { payments }
                    {/* {PHOTO_DATA.map((item, i) => {
                        return <Photo key={i} {...item} press={this.props.press} />
                    })} */}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here is that you are treating [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) the wrong way. JSX tags is not something that you can emit as plain text (like you would emit HTML with PHP). When you buildyour project, this `<View a={1} b={2} />` compiles into this `React.createElement('View', { a:1, b: 2})` so your code is not a valid JSX

You should use `.map` for this `PHOTO_DATA.map(item => <Photo key={i} /* your other props */ />` this will give you rendered Photo components

Another problem here is that you also want to split items by groups of 3 for the sake of styling. You should be using styles for that, e.g. create a parent `View`, put all the rendered `<Photo />`s inside and use flexbox to style your elements accordingly (refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546550/flexbox-4-items-per-row) on how to do that, for example)

But if you still want to know how to do what you did with JSX instead of styles, you would first have to [split array in chunks of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks) (here you'd end up with array of arrays of 3 items each), then use `.map` to render Views with Photos inside, e.g.

```
return (
    {chunkedArray.map(group =>
      <View>
        {group.map(photo => <Photo />)}
      </View>
    )}
  )
```