# Displaying a specific number of item on a row and making them scroll-able when the screen size reduces - Flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to flex box, I want my images to be able to display four Images on a row which becomes scroll-able when the screen size reduces, how do i achieve that?

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">

  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">

  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">

  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">

  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">

  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
  
  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
  
  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flexbox: 4 items per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546550/flexbox-4-items-per-row)

Comment: Not totally, i need to make this images scroll-able when the screen size is smaller

Comment: When you say scrollable what are you talking about? like, left to right? The answer to the referenced question is "scrollable." It isn't just cutting it off.

Comment: either ways, from left to right and vice-versa

Comment: If you are wanting four to a row, why not give them an width of 25%.  Then give your container a min-width so it will stay that big and scroll when your screen size is too small

Comment: I really don't understand, please show a demonstration?

Comment: maybe,overflow is missing on the div and , min-width to only show 4 image at the time, and also margin for img instead justify-content ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of flexbox, use grid, and give the container a fixed min-width:

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
  justify-content: space-around;
  grid-gap:10px;
  max-width:500px;
  min-width:450px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">

  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">

  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">

  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">

  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">

  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">

  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">

  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make a single row scrollable?

Answer (score 0):

> from my comment trying to figure out your question
>
> -*maybe,overflow is missing on the div and , min-width to only show 4 image at the time, and also margin for img instead justify-content ?*-

```css
div {
  display:flex;
  overflow:auto;
}

img {
min-width:20%;
margin: 0 2.5%;
height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">

  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">

  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">

  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">

  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">

  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
  
  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
  
  <img height="50" width="50" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1226302/pexels-photo-1226302.jpeg" alt="">
</div>
```