# How to display 4 images positioned proportionally on screen

Tags: android, css, react-native

I want 4 images to be proportionally displayed on screen and I am really bad with CSS generally, so I can't figure out here how to do it. I was trying with flex, to set it on `1` and then on sub-views to set it on `0.25`, but it doesn't work, even tried `flexWrap`, still nothing, it's always in one row, as I set flexDirection to be `row`

```
<View style={getStyle(styles, ["container"], this.props.theme)}>
    <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => this.onHandlePress("DevicesNavigator")}
      >
        <Icon name="pencil" color="yellow" size={100} />
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <Text style={styles.imageText}>
        {strings("initialTab.devicesTab")}
      </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => this.onHandlePress("ReportsNavigatior")}
      >
        <Icon name="tablet" color="yellow" size={100} />
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <Text style={styles.imageText}>{strings("initialTab.reports")}</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => this.onHandlePress("SyncNavigatior")}
      >
        <Icon name="refresh" color="yellow" size={100} />
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <Text style={styles.imageText}>{strings("initialTab.sync")}</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => this.onHandlePress("SettingsNavigatior")}
      >
        <Icon name="gear" color="yellow" size={100} />
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <Text style={styles.imageText}>{strings("initialTab.settings")}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
```

**And style**:

```
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignContent: "center",
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  containerLIGHT_THEME: {
    backgroundColor: colors.initialFourScreenBackgroundColorLight
  },
  containerDARK_THEME: {
    backgroundColor: colors.initialFourScreenBackgroundColorDark
  },
  itemContainer: {
    flex: 0.25
  },
  imageText: {
    color: "green"
  }
});
```

**Display**

[image]

Comment: Please show some demo image, how you want to display images?

Comment: @KaranMehta I post it in edit, u can check screen shot, that the idea

Comment: Image Link not working

Comment: @Awais what does it say? It's light shot uploaded, u should be able to see it

Comment: this error message `The requested URL /qjx9v0 was not found on this server.`, and also is it possible to post a minimal working example

Comment: @Awais how about now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work.

**STYLE**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  containerLIGHT_THEME: {
    backgroundColor: colors.initialFourScreenBackgroundColorLight
  },
  containerDARK_THEME: {
    backgroundColor: colors.initialFourScreenBackgroundColorDark
  },
  itemContainer: {
    marginTop: "15%",
    marginLeft: "20%"
  },
  imageText: {
    color: "green"
  }
});
```

Make it `flex-wrap`, as others suggested, make it go in `row`, and just set margins.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1000px;
}

.item {
  width: 50%;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
</div>
```

You can set the width of the container & item, thereby creating a break point and wrap the items, here is a JSFiddle with dummy images
https://jsfiddle.net/ah1ws6oj/

Comment: I get what u did here, but still can't reproduce on react- native "CSS", because it is different, I have everything in single row

Answer (score 0):

Its simple i use Simple `flex` with some `media queries` for mobile

Solution Below

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  flex: 1 0 21%; 
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .child {
  flex: 1 0 35%;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

> With `flex-grow: 1` defined in the flex shorthand [Ref]

(https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

In your case `.child` = `.itemContainer` and `.parent` = `.container`

I updated this example `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546550/flexbox-4-items-per-row/45384426`

Comment: I have problem because this is not CSS, it's react-native CSS and some properties are different, I can't make it to go in row, it's always in one column

Comment: But you wrote some style in your question just update that no need of html change

Comment: Yes, that is react-native CSS, it's similar to regular, but attributes are different

Comment: I am also using same attribute just changed the value, like you wrote `flex: 0.25` and i wrote `flex: 1 0 21%;`

Comment: There is no percentage in react-native CSS, I tried equivalents of that, still no progress. And this `flex: 1 0 35%;` doesn't exist in react-native CSS

Comment: U can only set `flex: 1 (or some number)`

Comment: Oh sorry now i got it, well i am not a pro of react but anyhow i will try it later on, and will get back to you