# *ngFor flexbox row direction

Tags: angular, flexbox, ngfor

In Angular 5, `*ngFor` generate `<div>` elements in a column direction instead of row direction:

**html**:

```
    <div class="charts"  *ngFor="let chart of chartEntities$ | async; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn"
          style="padding-top: 0.5em">
          <div class="item">
            <span style="background-color: rgb(127, 140, 255); height:120px;"> number {{i}}
            </span>
          </div>
    </div>
```

**css**:

```
    .charts{
      display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
    }

    .item{
      display: flex;
      flex: 1
    }
```

How can I change it to all elements be in the same row?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rearrange as

```
<div class="charts" style="padding-top: 0.5em">
      <div class="item" *ngFor="let chart of chartEntities$ | async; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
        <span style="background-color: rgb(127, 140, 255); height:120px;"> number {{i}}
        </span>
      </div>
</div>
```

The `display: flex; flex-direction: row;` should be on the parent `div`

Comment: Thanks, I did it, second step is to control how many 'span' will be in each row.
I want to have 2 'span' in each row. I I set 'flex-basis:50%' it not works

Comment: I add to 'item' 'flex-basis:50%' and 'flex-wrap: wrap;'  it not works

Comment: @larryckey: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546550/flexbox-4-items-per-row . Take a look at `flex: 0 1 calc(20% - 8px);` . A small demo code https://plnkr.co/edit/f6s8D3JB4pplLUjk?open=lib%2Fscript.js .

Comment: thanks, your examples helped me, I made a few changes and all works great, Thanks

Comment: @larryckey : awesome !

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `*ngFor` to your `item`, not the `charts`:

```
<div class="charts" style="padding-top: 0.5em">
  <div class="item" *ngFor="let chart of chartEntities$ | async; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
    <span style="background-color: rgb(127, 140, 255); height:120px;">
      number {{i}}
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>on a side note, don't use inline styling like that. Those need to be moved to a component css file</sub>