# how to display <div> next to each other within a for loop?(laravel)

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working on a alumni portal where I need to display the committee member details. I need to print like 4 members in a line and next 4 in the next line. Any solution would be helpful.
[image]

```
<h2>Member Details</h2>
    <div class="jumbotron container">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" id="mediumButton" data-target="#mediumModal" data-attr="{{ route('add_details')}}" title="Add Institute Details"> <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="container main" id="wrapper"> 
                @foreach ($members as $member)
                    <div class="img-box">
                        <pre>
                        <img src="/uploads/image/{{ $member->image }}" width="100" height="100"/>
                        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; {{ $member->id }}<br/>
                        <a> &nbsp;  {{ $member->name }}</a>
                        
                        <!-- @if(($member->id) >=5 )
                        <span style="white-space: pre-line">
                        </span> 
                        @endif
                        </pre> -->
                    </div>
                @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: use Bootstrap Grid. see here https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp

Comment: How do I limit 4 members per line.

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546550/flexbox-4-items-per-row

Comment: Grid: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flexbox: 4 items per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546550/flexbox-4-items-per-row)

Comment: It didn't work with this method maybe because of loop. But it did work with the below comment. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use Bootstrap try this

```
<div class="row">
  @foreach ($members as $member)
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="img-box">
        <pre>
         <img src="/uploads/image/{{ $member->image }}" width="100" height="100"/>
       &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; {{ $member->id }}<br/>
         <a> &nbsp;  {{ $member->name }}</a>
        </pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: It displays 1 member per line.

Comment: are you use bootstrap?

Comment: Yes. I'm using.

Comment: change col-3 to col-md-3,
what version of Bootstrap do you use?

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 3, col-md-3 worked. Thank You..

Comment: Can you edit your above answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: ok, already changed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Add "display:grid;" to the container "div" tag You need to define the property.

Comment: share as a comment, not as an answer.