# How to fix the css to keep 4 cards in a row while they are center aligned?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

Facing an issue with a css property (Flex) . I have multiple cards and i want it to be 4 cards per row so that irrespective for screen size it will always have 4 cards per row. Since i am using display element as Flex it adjusted according to screen size. Very new to this front end dev work, can you please check and fix my CSS property to align 4 cards in a row.

here is the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-feynman-we6n9s?file=/src/productsConfig.js

Basically here i want 4 cards per row.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flexbox: 4 items per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546550/flexbox-4-items-per-row)

Comment: Is your card allowed to grow in width (e.g. 25% of container width) or it has to stay the same size?

Comment: same size to be kept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using flex, and since you want the width of the cards to be fixed (300px), and assuming you're only working on large screens, to guarantee displaying 4 elements of 300ps in a row, it's best to also set the width of the parent to 1500px for example, in this case only 4 elements with margins, paddings will be displayed in a single row.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1500px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.react-card-flip {
  flex: 1 0 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="react-card-flip"></div>
  <div class="react-card-flip"></div>
  <div class="react-card-flip"></div>
  <div class="react-card-flip"></div>
  <div class="react-card-flip"></div>
  <div class="react-card-flip"></div>
  <div class="react-card-flip"></div>
  <div class="react-card-flip"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: somehow it not working in my code.. I updated my code, you can see it there.. somehow its getting adjusted according to screen size. can you please post a working code

Comment: In your code you should apply the CSS part of card on the react-card-flip class not on card class, because the direct children elements of the flex parent element (container) are the element with class react-card-flip, not card, I updated my code to be adapted to your classes naming could you check and tell me.

Comment: Thanks Amel.  I tried, when screen is changing the margin between the cards gets increased.

Comment: basically card width and hight should not change. Only thing is there should be 4 cards in a row and the container should be center aligned. Not able to make container fixed

Comment: But what to do if the width of the device is 800px for example, how to display 4 elements of 300px in a single line in a device of 800px of width?

Comment: Apart from that, if we suppose that you are using your app on only big devices, I think the perfect solution will be to fix also the width of the container to make it 1500 px for example, In this case, you will be sure only 4 elements of 300px will be displayed in a single row, not more.

Comment: in smaller device, there will be scroll. as you said if the width of the container is fixed, that would solve

Comment: I updated my code here you can check, and I added a margin auto to display center the elements

Answer (score 1):

You can add flex-basis, it sets the size of the content box, so your css `flex-basis: 25%` on class `.react-card-flip`

**Update**

if you don't want increase your space then try this:

```
.react-card-flip:nth-child(3n+1):not(:first-child) {
  break-after: always;
}
```

this code just simply found your 4th element and add a break on it. Just try to decrease your page using `ctrl` + scroll your mouse to see. It `max 4` cards per row.

try on [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-grothendieck-zjqvmh?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: I dont want to increase the space between cards

Comment: See my update, I think it simplest way.

Comment: seems to be not working. can you post a working code using codesandbox

Comment: just added sandbox link, it stay maximum 4 cards per row

Comment: not working: https://zjqvmh.csb.app/ . please use a bigger screen or use zoom to see effect

Comment: do you mean exactly 4 cards per row, both MIN 4 cards per row and MAX 4 cards per row?

Comment: 4 cards per row

Comment: not really working in big screen

Comment: can you please give your screenshot, I need to know what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251717/discussion-between-shankar-panda-and-eve).

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding this style to your style.css file for responsive auto card wrap on space.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  width: calc(25% - 40px);
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: can you post a working code. I tried but not working. you can use codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

I thought the problem is "incorrect level".

Press "f12" in https://we6n9s.csb.app/, then you will see the 1st level is "container".
The 2nd level is "react-card-flip".
The 3rd level is "react-card-flipper".
The 4th level is "react-card-front".
The 5th level is "card".

Maybe you could use `.react-card-flip` but not `.card`

```css
.react-card-flip {
  position: flex;
  flex: 1 0 22%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 22%;
  height: 300px;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: card width to me remain constant.